# How to display product on home page category wise which is checked(custom attribute) in magento backend admin

Tags: magento

How can we display new products on home page category wise which are selected using custom attribute "Show"(drop down or check box) in magento product list grid or product upload page?

Answer (score 1):

To find product for a particular attribute in category, use the following code:

```
$id=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);

$_products=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id);
$_productcollection=$_products->getProductCollection();

foreach($_productcollection->getAllIds() as $_productid)
{

    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_productid);

    //print $_product->getName().$_product->getShowfront()."<br/>";
    $showfnt=$_product->getShowfront();

    if($showfnt==1)
    {
     echo $_product->getname()."<br/>";
      /* write here you grid or list code for display product */
    }

}
```

In the above code I created `showfront` attribute so you write your attribute name there.

Comment: Hi Tim Medora , thank u very much for your reply but I'm new to magneto and programming field can you please explain step by step that where i have to edit this code and here i am using drop down custom attribute in manage products page .

Comment: Hi , finally i can display products which are checked using custom attribute by using above piece of code from new.phtml page but i want to display only 3 products validation from each category  with category name .i.e

category1 
img1 img2 img3

category 2
img1 img2 img3
.
.
.
how can i achieve this plz guide me